# What is a type string (template meta-programming) and what does it do?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I've heard a bit about what a typestring is: a compile-time string that is coerced to a type for a definition or comparison. If my logic is right, this means that I can easily dynamically create and compare types; perhaps I could even find a way to narrow variants back to a concrete type using this. Have I got that right?

Comment: This question severely lacks some sample code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your description if you've got that right, at least if we're talking about type strings as implemented [here](https://github.com/irrequietus/typestring).

Type strings are just compile-time strings: they can be used / inspected via template meta programming. For example, you could have a template that converted a type-level string to upper case, and the conversion would be done at compile time.

You cannot, however, generically convert any typestring to the type it refers, nor can you convert any type to a typestring. So for example, given `typdef typestring_is("int") int_typestring`, there is no generic way to get the type `int` from `int_typestring`. The converse is also not generically possible: you cannot get `int_typestring` from just the type `int` generically (there is no way to write a generic template `to_type_string<T>` that returns the type string for a given type T such that it works for all types T).